# Why Doesn’t My Game’s Trial Play Function Take Effect?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I have integrated the trial play function provided by the HMS Core Game Service SDK 5.0.1.302 into my game and completed the following as instructed by the official documentation:
1.Applying to enable the forcible identity verification function.
2.Adding code snippet for implementing trial play to my game code.
However, when my game was launched and the identity verification pop-up was displayed, the trial play option was not available, which means that the function did not take effect. How can I make the function take effect?

Answer (score 0):

The following are some of the prerequisites for enabling the trial play function:

1. The integrated Game Service SDK version must be 5.0.1 or later.
2. The forcible identity verification has been enabled.
3. Code relating to the trial play function has been added.
4. The default authorization parameter of the game must be `DEFAULT_AUTH_REQUEST_PARAM_GAME`.

[image]

For Details,check [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/game-login-0000001050121526?ha_source=hms1).

Answer (score 0):

As Shirley already pointed out, please double-check all those 4 prereqs, make sure they are all in place. One common mistake people usually made is as follows:

[image]

Please see if that falls into your category. If you still encounter errors, please refer to this [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/server-error-codes-0000001062371380-V5) to find out more error code info.